# Reticulate fails automatic configuration in R package

Tags: python, r, github-actions, reticulate, pkgdown

I'm working on a R package, that makes use of `reticulate` to call some functions of a Python package I implemented, installable through `pip`.

Following its documentation, I setup the `reticulate` automatic configuration of  Python dependencies as follows, in the `DESCRIPTION` file of my package:

```
Config/reticulate:
  list(
    packages = list(
      list(package="my_python_package", pip=TRUE)
    )
  )
```

where `my_python_package` is the Python package I need to use.

If I install the package locally, where I have the required Python package already installed, everything works fine.
However, if I try to install and use the R package in an environment without the Python package already installed, I get the following error:

```
Error in py_module_import(module, convert = convert) : 
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_python_package'

Detailed traceback:
  File "/home/runner/work/_temp/Library/reticulate/python/rpytools/loader.py", line 39, in _import_hook
    module = _import(
```

as if `reticulate` is not able to configure correctly the environment.

Also, the Python package should not be the problem, since when it is installed, I am able to import it and use its functions with no errors.

From the `reticulate` documentation it seems `Config/reticulate: ...` is all is needed, but maybe I am missing something.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed this issue https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/issues/997 on the `reticulate` GitHub repository. Apparently, the automatic configuration through `Config/reticulate` only works if a conda environment is already loaded.

Therefore, I think the only way to configure the correct environment is on the `.onLoad` function:

- check if Anaconda is installed, otherwhise launch the Miniconda installation through `reticulate::install_miniconda()`
- check if the environment is already present, otherwise create create it through `reticulate::conda_create(envname)`,
- install the `Python` dependencies if necessary through `reticulate::conda_install(envname, packages)`,
- load the configured environment.

In this way, the first time the package is loaded, the environment will be correctly created. 
After that, the environment will be automatically loaded.